# HTML div within body resizing whole page

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a page for my blog, and I discovered that when I have my `div.page-content` within the `body`, it's glitching out and resizing the whole `body` to the top of the div... I need the `body` to fill the viewport no matter what.

**Relevant HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="page-content"> <!-- THIS IS MY .page-content DIV -->
        asdasd
    </div>
</body>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%; width: 100%; /* Shouldn't this make the page guaranteed to fill the viewport? */
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    color: #424242;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /* I'm gonna have a blurred background image */
}

.page-content {
    min-height: 300px; width: 600px;
    margin: 60px auto 30px auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deansheather/5et5kgsn/

I have not an idea if there is a javascript way to fix this, but I'd prefer CSS and HTML only answers please.

I'm sorry about the really weird explanation, it's what came into my head.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the .page-content class height to auto. Think your problem solved.try this:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    color: #424242;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /* I'm gonna have a blurred background image */
}    
.page-content {
        min-height: 300px; width: 600px; height: auto;
        margin: 60px auto 30px auto;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work for me at all. The problem is still occurring. Check the same Codepen as the question: http://codepen.io/deansheather/pen/vNdqGy.

Comment: I need the viewport to be filled by the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Even your JSFiddle shows something different to what I want. I need the body tag to fill the page and viewport. I recoloured the elements in my Codepen, what I need is for the purple (`<body>`) element to fill the screen.

Comment: Use this to your html, body{ } block
overflow: hidden;

Comment: `overflow: auto;` worked for me... Thanks for your help anyways. :)